# Laravel Pivot Table Issue. Foreign key Link Not Found

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-10

## Laravel Eloquent attach - link not found on the pivot tabe

Hey Im Have Two Models
GymOwner

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;

class GymOwner extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable=[
        'gym_name',
    'owner_name',
    'registration_number',
    'contact_phone',
    'address',
    'description',
    'logo',
    'opening_hours',
    'address',
    'social_media_links',
    'legal_docs',
    ];

    public function User(){
        return $this->BelongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function GymMember(){

        return $this->hasMany(GymMember::class);
    }

    public function GymOwnerPayments(){
        return $this->hasMany(GymOwnerPayment::class);
    }

    public function GymMemberPayments(){
        return $this->hasMany(GymMemberPayment::class);
    }
    public function GymTrainerPayments(){
        return $this->hasMany(GymTrainerPayment::class);
    }

    public function GymTrainers(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(GymTrainer::class,'gym_owner_gym_trainer','gym_owner_id','gym_trainer_id');
    }
}
```

GymTrainer -

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class GymTrainer extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function User(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function GymTrainerPayments(){
        return $this->hasMany(GymTrainerPayment::class);
    }

    public function GymOwners(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(GymOwner::class,'gym_owner_gym_trainer','gym_trainer_id','gym_owner_id');
    }
}
```

Then This is My migration for pivot table -

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('gym_owner_gym_trainer', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('gym_owner_id');
            $table->foreign('gym_owner_id')->references('id')->on('gym_owners');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('gym_trainer_id');
            $table->foreign('gym_trainer_id')->references('id')->on('gym_trainers');
            
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('table_gym_owner_gym_trainer');
    }
};
```

Then This is how Creating Gym Trainer happens -

```
 public function storeGymTraineruser(CreateGymTrainerAccountRequest $request)
    {
        $input = $request->validated();

        $User = User::create([
            'name' => $input['name'],
            'email' => $input['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($input['password']),
        ]);

        $User->addRole('gym_trainer');

        $gymTrainer = new GymTrainer();
        $gymTrainer->user_id = $User->id;
        $gymTrainer->save();
        $gymOwner = GymOwner::find($request->user()->id); // Assuming you have the gym_owner_id available
        $gymTrainer->GymOwners()->attach($gymOwner->id);

        return redirect()->route('gym-trainers.index')->with('message', "Gym Trainer User Account Has Been Created Successfully");
    }
```

Everything seems to work fine but in database when i check pivot table gym_trainer_id field it says Link Not Found. but correct Gym Trainer id is there only its not refering to any actual gymTrainers in the table

I tried recreating the database table and attaching. but Dint work i tried attaching this way too

```
$gymOwner = GymOwner::find($gym_owner_id); // Assuming you have the gym_owner_id available
$gymTrainer->GymOwner()->attach($gymOwner);
```

And there is another thing. In the pivot table created_at and updated_at fields are null. There are not filed when i attach

Comment: So if I understand correctly, when you perform the `attach` it creates a line in the pivot table with the correct `id` values for the gym owner `id` and gym trainer `id`, but it is just not linked to the other table - Is this it?

Comment: Your line in the down method of your migration of `Schema::dropIfExists('table_gym_owner_gym_trainer');` should be `Schema::dropIfExists('gym_owner_gym_trainer');` - see if this helps. It could be your down method is not actually taking down the correct table, and hence doesn't have the correct schema.

Comment: @Coola yes. That is the problem. I fixed the down method. but i still has the issue

Comment: Try adding the `constrained()` method on your foreign key migration lines. See docs here https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Comment: @Coola I tried adding foreign id and constrained but still i have the issue. never faced anything like this before

Comment: @Coola  And there is another thing. in the pivot table created_at and updated_at fields are null. there are not filed when i attach

Comment: did you use the `withTimestamps()` method on the relationship definition?

Comment: The created_at field should be fixed `withTimestamps()`. Your line `$gymTrainer->save();` can you dd() after that for `$gymTrainer` and share what that has?